# How to compile enterpise mib into python 3.6?

Tags: python, snmp

I've used this commad: `pip install pysnmp-mibs` and it installed set of python compiled `snmp.py-es` in dir: 
`C:\Users\mljolje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pysnmp_mibs`.

How can I add and compile additional enterprise or custom mib to that dir?
I tried to bulid script for sending traps and for some custom traps I need custom mib.
I tried this: `python mibdump.py Cisco-Syslog-mib.mib`

and got this:

```
C:\Users\mljolje\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Tools\scripts>python mibdump.py Cisco-Syslog-mib.mib
Source MIB repositories: file:///usr/share/snmp/mibs, http://mibs.snmplabs.com/asn1/@mib@
Borrow missing/failed MIBs from: http://mibs.snmplabs.com/pysnmp/notexts/@mib@
Existing/compiled MIB locations: pysnmp.smi.mibs, pysnmp_mibs
Compiled MIBs destination directory: C:\Users\mljolje\PySNMP Configuration\mibs
MIBs excluded from code generation: INET-ADDRESS-MIB, PYSNMP-USM-MIB, RFC-1212, RFC-1215, RFC1065-SMI, RFC1155-SMI, RFC1158-MIB, RFC1213-MIB, SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB, SNMP-TARGET-MIB, S
NMPv2-CONF, SNMPv2-SMI, SNMPv2-TC, SNMPv2-TM, TRANSPORT-ADDRESS-MIB
MIBs to compile: Cisco-Syslog-mib
Destination format: pysnmp
Parser grammar cache directory: not used
Also compile all relevant MIBs: yes
Rebuild MIBs regardless of age: no
Dry run mode: no
Create/update MIBs: yes
Byte-compile Python modules: yes (optimization level no)
Ignore compilation errors: no
Generate OID->MIB index: no
Generate texts in MIBs: no
Keep original texts layout: no
Try various file names while searching for MIB module: yes
Created/updated MIBs:
Pre-compiled MIBs borrowed:
Up to date MIBs:
Missing source MIBs: Cisco-Syslog-mib
Ignored MIBs:
Failed MIBs:
```

so I don't know how to do that. I'm new to all this.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. What is it that you want to achieve? And why would you want to specifically put additional mibs in that same dir?

Comment: As I understood this command pip install pysnmp-mibs just install certain compiled snmp mibs into xxx.py so it is easier to create for example snmp traps variables (you don't need to write whole OID number in call,just write name of mib: name of variable) ...and that is why i want to add some more enterprise mib to my .py dir.